# Port Forward not working

Tags: port-forwarding, fritzbox

So I tried to port forward for a game server but it isn't working while it says it is on. Any idea's why this is the case?

some screenshots:

> [image]

> [image]

I have a FritzBox BTW.

Comment: Is this for ARK Survival Evolved? Where did you get the information about the ports from? Most ports listed on the internet is unfortunately plain wrong. How did you check whether it works or not?

Comment: Yeah this is for indeed for ARK. I got them from an ark 'youtuber'.

Comment: [Port Forwarding on Your Router for Ark: Survival Evolved](https://portforward.com/ark-survival-evolved/)

Answer (score 0):

The [ARK wiki at Fandom.com](https://ark.fandom.com/wiki/Dedicated_Server_Setup#Network) lists the following ports:

- TCP:

  - 27020 Remote Console (optional)
- UDP:

  - 7777 “Game Client Port”
  - 7778 “Raw UDP socket port”
  - 27015 Steam Game Server Browser

So you have some unneeded port forwards set up (like TCP 7777) but you are missing one (UDP 7778).

Unless you want to remotely control your game server, I strongly suggest you not forward port 27020.

Comment: The problem is not that the server is not working. They say they are open but when i check them using an port checker or just pinging them in cmd they say the ports are closed. Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: You cannot easily check UDP port forwards, because UDP is connectionless. You certainly cannot ping them. The only way to check them is to be outside the network (very important) and attempt to connect to the game server.